# What is the minimum office 2013 edition that can be used for VSTO development?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, vsto

I only need to develop for Excel and maybe word, so would Office Home edition installed on the development machine be enough? or Professional is the minimum that can be used for development?

I am using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: I think home edition should be enough for development. Why dont you give a try?

Comment: Because I got to buy it first. The trial versions keep dying with error message were already installed previously although it was not. Trying to figure out what is cheapest option.

Comment: better choose the right rather thn cheap product, also beware of license clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the extensions (and you **do** want to use the extensions), you'll need to buy **any** commercial version.

However, if you're open to a trial version, you have always the option of installing a virtual machine (for testing purposes, of course).

Also - you wrote *minimum office 2013 edition* Is that a typo? I'm assuming you refer to VS. Correct?

Comment: VS Professional 2012, Office 2013

Comment: As far I'm informed, the version of Office doesn't matter. However, in order to develop you'll need to install VSTO and that excludes the free Express version of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

You can sign up for an Office 365 Developer Site at: msdn.

breadcrumb: Start building apps for Office and SharePoint > Sign up for an Office 365 Developer Site

They'll offer you "1-year Office 365 Developer Subscription as a benefit" to build and test apps for the Office and SharePoint stores.

Alternatively, you can buy an Office 365 developer subscription (with one user license). This subscription costs $99.00 per year.

Hope this helps.